# JSF + Weld CDI + WebService (over Jetty9) does not work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, maven-3, cdi, db4o

I just don't get what the big mistake is that I'm doing...

It's just not possible for me to get Weld CDI to work. Before I integrated CDI into my webapp (JSF + PrimeFaces + DB4O + Jersey), everything worked mostly fine.

Since I replaced the @ManagedBean stuff with @Named and so on and did changed my pom for using CDI, Jetty does not start anymore.

**SOLVED** *(see UPDATE #1)*

I used ManagedBeans in the past, but needed the CDI for injection withing webservices.

See *UPDATE 2* for that.

---

My project-structure:

[image]

---

My Exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-001524 Unable to load proxy class for bean Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface javax.enterpr
ise.inject.Instance using classloader WebAppClassLoader=343602030@147af36e
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:318)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.AbstractFacadeBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractFacadeBean.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:129)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:120)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by:
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/enterpris
e/util/TypeLiteral"
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2641)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1457)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.addMethodsFromClass(ProxyFactory.java:523)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.addMethods(ProxyFactory.java:478)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:412)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:311)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.AbstractFacadeBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractFacadeBean.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:129)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:120)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

---

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This is the project descriptor for the examples of my components -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>DB4O-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DB4O-Web</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>DB4O-Test</groupId>
        <artifactId>DB4O-Test-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.db4o</groupId>
            <artifactId>db4o-full-java5</artifactId>
            <version>8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository for jstl 1.2 -->
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>db4o-repo</id>
            <url>http://source.db4o.com/maven/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>DB4O-Test</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--option>weld</option-->
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <reload>automatic</reload>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <jettyXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml</jettyXml>
                    <contextXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <description>debug web.xml</description>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default)
            See JSF Specification 2.5.3
        </description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>de.mypackage.guide.ws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

</web-app>
```

---

My beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

---

My jetty-config.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

---

My jetty-env.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="BeanManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx" />
        </Arg>
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg />
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

---

Example class:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import de.mypackage.guide.model.Device;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 08.08.13
 * Time: 08:21
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DeviceService implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DatabaseService databaseService;

    public DeviceService() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public void sendDevice() {
        Client create = Client.create();
        WebResource service = create.resource( "http://localhost:8080/ws" );
        System.out.println( service.path( "register" ).path( "device" ).path( "meinDevice" )
                .type( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN ).put(String.class) );
    }

    public Collection<Device> getAllDevices() {
        return this.databaseService.retrieveAll(Device.class);
    }

    public DatabaseService getDatabaseService() {
        return databaseService;
    }

    public void setDatabaseService(DatabaseService databaseService) {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public Device getDevice(String deviceName) {
        return this.databaseService.retrieveFiltered(Device.class, "regId", deviceName).toArray(new Device[0])[0];
    }

    public void saveDevice(Device device) {
        this.databaseService.store(device);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**UPDATE #1:**

After solving my **exception above by following the commentary below the first answer from John Ament**, I have another problem.

Now I get a NPE. Seems that my service won't get injected at all. By reading my log output it says that CDI support is enabled, so maybe it's some configuration (beans.xml etc.) problem?

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.mypackage.guide.ws.RegistrationService.device(RegistrationService.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

2013-08-09 07:52:43.853:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1061696789-23: /ws/register/device/meinDevice
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.mypackage.guide.ws.RegistrationService.device(RegistrationService.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

I checked the injection within the services and they work (getting some test-output from another service), so the problem lies within the webservice <---> CDI stuff.

Could there be a problem with the different contexts of cdi, webservices and jsf?

```
@Path("/register")
public class RegistrationService {

    @Inject
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @GET
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Path("/get/{device}")
    public String getDevice(@PathParam("device") String device) {
        return this.deviceService.getDevice(device).getRegId();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path( "/device/{device}" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    public String device(@PathParam("device") String device) {
        this.deviceService.saveDevice(new Device(device));
        System.out.println("Erfolgreich!");
        return "Device: " + device;
    }

    public DeviceService getDeviceService() {
        return deviceService;
    }

    public void setDeviceService(DeviceService deviceService) {
        this.deviceService = deviceService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Maven version are you using? 3.1?? I had the same problem when trying to run my app through jetty:run goal (maven-jetty-plugin 9.x) and Maven 3.1. I've just revert my Maven to 3.0.x version and now it goes well.

Comment: Something I hadn't considered at all. Just looked up my version and it is 3.1.0 indeed. Will append my experience after trying out.

Comment: **UPDATE:** You were right. After downgrading Maven to 3.0.X (5 in my case), I tried the Weld 2.0.3.Final dependency again and it worked without any problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the api jars for CDI aren't being loaded, you have them as `provided` which excludes them from runtime.

Comment: Also, since you're using weld servlet 2.x you should switch your CDI libs to use CDI 1.1 APIs.

Comment: @LightGuard - You mean the web-api? I changed it, but that did not have any effect. However, what John Ament said had a big effect. With changing to the latest 1.1.x version, the exception was gone. After that I got another exception, mentioned here stackoverflow.com/q/3424207/1343241 which I solved with his solution. But how should I've known that the version is the problem I battled about 8 hours with?

Comment: On the forums and even the weld site it says that Weld 2 is the RI for CDI 1.1.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't get Weld 2 working. By changing to 1.1.x, it worked. Don't know where, but I read somewhere on the official page that Weld 2 can't work with ContextListeners or Servlets atm.
Maybe that is what breakes my build. Guessed that the Jetty version may be responsible, but I also read that Weld 2 only works with Jetty7 and further.
Would like to use Weld 2, but I can't get the Linkage Error go away. Seems to collide with some other API, but don't know which and how to solve.